# How can I storage an input's value in an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, object, input, radio-button

I am making an app that counts calories and cost of daily meals. To get the inputs from the html form I'm using this:

```
// GET INPUTS
let breakfast =  document.getElementsByName('breakfast');
let lunch = document.getElementsByName('lunch');
let dinner = document.getElementsByName('dinner');
let snack = document.getElementsByName('snack');


// Checked inputs
function getCheckedElement(x){
    let result;
    for(let i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        if(x[i].checked){
            result = x[i].value
        }
    }
    return result;
};


let breakfastChoice = getCheckedElement(breakfast);
let lunchChoice = getCheckedElement(lunch);
let dinnerChoice = getCheckedElement(dinner);
let snackChoice = getCheckedElement(snack);
```

Then, I put then into an object that gets the values from a _menu:

```
// FACTORY FUNCTION FOR EACH DAY OF THE WEEK
const dayFactory = (br, ln, din, sck, calBurned) => {
    return {
     breakfast: _memory._breakfast[br],
     lunch: _memory._lunch[ln],
     dinner: _memory._dinner[din],
     snack: _memory._snack[sck],
     calBurned: calBurned,
     }
  };

let day = {
      today: dayFactory(breakfastChoice, lunchChoice, dinnerChoice, snackChoice, 0),
...
```

But it doesn't work.

this is the html form:

```
<form method="GET" action="index.html">
            <h2>Breakfast</h2>
            <input id='porridge' name='breakfast' type='radio' value="porridge" class="breakfast" checked>
            <label for='porridge'>Porridge</label>
            <input id='toast' name='breakfast' type='radio' value="toast" class="breakfast">
            <label for='toast'>Toast</label>
            <br>
            <h2>Lunch</h2>
            <input id='soup' name='lunch' type="radio" value='soup' class="lunch" checked>
            <label for='soup'>Soup</label>
            <input id='pasta' name='lunch' type='radio' value='pasta' class="lunch">
            <label for='pasta'>Pasta</label>
            <input id='pizza-lunch' name='lunch' type='radio' value="pizza-lunch" class="lunch">
            <label for='pizza-lunch'>Pizza</label>
            <input id='burrito-lunch' name="lunch" type="radio" value="burrito-lunch" class="lunch">
            <label for='burrito-lunch'>Burrito</label>
            <input id='falafel-lunch' name='lunch' type='radio' value="falafel-lunch" class="lunch">
            <label for='falafel-lunch'>Falafel</label>
            <br>
            <h2>Dinner</h2>
            <input id='yogurt' name='dinner' type='radio' value="yogurt" class="dinner" checked>
            <label for='yogurt'>Yogurt</label>
            <input id='pizza' name='dinner' type='radio' value="pizza" class="dinner">
            <label for='pizza'>Pizza</label>
            <input id='burrito' name="dinner" type="radio" value="burrito" class="dinner">
            <label for='burrito'>Burrito</label>
            <input id='falafel' name='dinner' type='radio' value="falafel" class="dinner">
            <label for='falafel'>Falafel</label>
            <br>
            <h2>Snack</h2>
            <input type='checkbox' id='peanut-butter' name="snack" value="peanut-butter" class="snack" checked>
            <label for='peanut-butter'>Peanut Butter</label>
            <input id='cream-cheese' name="snack" type='checkbox' value="cream-cheese" class="snack">
            <label for='cream-cheese'>Cream Cheese</label>
            <input id='olives' name='snack' type="checkbox" value="olives" class="snack">
            <label for='olives'>Olives</label>
            <input id='almonds' name='snack' type="checkbox" value="almonds" class="snack">
            <label for='almonds'>Almonds</label>
            <input id='pop-corn' name='snack' type='checkbox' value="pop-corn" class="snack">
            <label for='pop-corn'>Pop Corn</label>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
         </form>
```

I am able to get the values when I log the function getCheckedElement(x) directly in the console, and when I call the function as a parameter in the factory function directly in the console, but I don't get the values when I try to log the variables that use this function.

This is the object where I store the calories and cost of the meals:

```
// LIST OF POSIBLE MEALS
const _memory = {
    _breakfast: {
        _porridge: {
            calories: 0,
            cost: 0,
        },
        _toast: {
            calories: 20,
            cost: 50,
        },
        _nothing: {
          calories: 0,
          cost: 0,
        },
        get nothing(){
            return this._nothing
        },
        get porridge(){
            return this._porridge
        },
        get toast(){
            return this._toast;
        }
    },
    _lunch: {
        _soup: {
            calories: 0,
            cost: 0,
        },
        _pasta: {
            calories: 0,
            cost: 0,
        },
       _nothing: {
          calories: 0,
          cost: 0,
        },
        _pizza: {
            calories: 0,
            cost: 0,
        },
        _burrito: {
            calories: 0,
            cost: 0,
        },
        _falafel: {
            calories: 0,
            cost: 0,
        },
        get pizza(){
            return this._pizza;
        },
        get burrito(){
            return this._burrito;
        },
        get falafel(){
            return this._falafel;
        },
        get nothing(){
            return this._nothing
        },
        get soup(){
            return this._soup;
        },
        get pasta(){
            return this._pasta;
        }

    },
    _dinner: {
        _yogurt: {
            calories: 0,
            cost: 0,
        },
        _nothing: {
          calories: 0,
          cost: 0,
        },
        _pizza: {
            calories: 0,
            cost: 0,
        },
        _burrito: {
            calories: 0,
            cost: 0,
        },
        _falafel: {
            calories: 0,
            cost: 0,
        },
        get pizza(){
            return this._pizza;
        },
        get burrito(){
            return this._burrito;
        },
        get falafel(){
            return this._falafel;
        },
        get nothing(){
            return this._nothing
        },
        get yogurt(){
            return this._yogurt;
        }

    },
    _snack: {
        _peanutButter: {
            calories: 0,
            cost: 0,
        },
        _hummus: {
            calories: 0,
            cost: 0,
        },
        _olives: {
            calories: 0,
            cost: 0,
        },
        _almonds: {
            calories: 0,
            cost: 0,
        },
        _creamCheese: {
            calories: 0,
            cost: 0,
        },
        _popCorn: {
            calories: 0,
            cost: 0,
        },
        _nothing: {
          calories: 0,
          cost: 0,
        },
        get nothing(){
            return this._nothing
        },
        get peanutButter(){
            return this._peanutButter;
        },
        get hummus(){
            return this._hummus;
        },
        get olives(){
            return this._olives;
        },
        get almonds(){
            return this._almonds;
        },
        get creamCheese(){
            return this._creamCheese;
        },
        get popCorn(){
            return this._popCorn;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: can you get the correct values on the form? could you put the form code too?

Comment: When I log getCheckedElement(breakfast) directly into the console I get the values. But no with the variables where I use that function.

Comment: what is this _memory on dayFactory?

Comment: The object where I storage the different meals as objects with entries like 'calories' and 'cost'

Comment: @Belen I think the main issue is with the _memory object, can you show that?

Comment: Yes, I just added it. thank you in advance!

Comment: I found the problem! My javascript link was in the <head> so javascript was loading before the form. Thank you anyway!